# Setting runtime options in Cloud Functions for Firebase v2

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

## The issue

I can't find a way to set runtime options (opts) for Cloud Functions for Firebase v2.  Each function has 2 entries in the documentation.  Auto-complete in VSCode always picks the first.  There seems to be no way to specify runtime options unless you can invoke the second.

### onDocumentCreated()

There are 2 functions for this in the documentation...

- `onDocumentCreated(document, handler)`
- `onDocumentCreated(opts, handler)`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.firestore.md

## Desired outcome

I want to be able to use `opts` and `handler` when I'm deploying functions, with the following code...

```
import {onDocumentCreated} from 'firebase-functions/v2/firestore';

export const exampleFunction = onDocumentCreated(
  {
    document: 'examples/{exampleId}',
    region: 'eu-west1',
  }, 
  async event => {
    console.log('My document was created')
  }
)
```

Comment: Ignoring for a moment that autocomplete doesn't work the way you expect, what's wrong with the code you've written?  Does it not compile or deploy?  What's the error? The first argument is a DocumentOptions object, which ultimately inherits from [GlobalOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.globaloptions.md#globaloptions_interface), which has a region property.

Comment: In the second description, the first argumet is a DocumentOptions object.  However, in the first description it is only a Document and the description states, "The Firestore document path to trigger on.".  I must admit that I haven't tried deploying it or running it, as there is confusion in the documentation, compounded by VSCode autocomplete.  I'll give it a try.